Should DFS check validity before or after call - traversing 2D Array
Are either of these more efficient or standard/readable? This is assuming that visited is not always empty/all False. The second option seems to do less checks: I wrote how many checks take place for visiting one layer further.
def dfs(row, col):
    if row >= len(grid) or row < 0 or col >= len(grid[row]) or col < 0 or not visited[row, col]:
        return
    visited[row, col] = True
    dfs(row + 1, col)
    dfs(row - 1, col)
    dfs(row, col + 1)
    dfs(row, col - 1)

Best case: 4 checks | Worst case: 20 checks
def dfs(row, col):
    visited[row, col] = True
    if row < len(grid) - 1 and not visited[row + 1][col]:
        dfs(row + 1, col)
    if row > 0 and not visited[row - 1][col]:
        dfs(row - 1, col)
    if col < len(grid[row]) - 1 and not visited[row][col + 1]:
        dfs(row, col + 1)
    if col > 0 and not visited[row][col - 1]:
        dfs(row, col - 1)

Best case: 4 checks | Worst case: 8 checks
Which one would you write and why?
